# PHP Variable Variables don't work... Why?

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm using a function that returns a Fetched Array from a Database ( PDO::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ).

this function returns A LOT OF COLUMNS and when I am editing all those columns in a Form, obviously I need the fields to be populate with the current data.

Code (modified for the question):

```
//returns something like $owner["name"], $owner["lastname"], 
//$owner["phone1"] ... and 53 fields more.

$owner = controllerGetOnwer($ownerID);

//So I used a foreach to create VARIABLE VARIABLES
foreach($owner as $key=>$value) {
     ${$key} = $value; //you get something like $name = <what is in that column>
}
```

I am gonna use this form in a lot of pages, not only for owners, but also for customers, administrators, and so on... That's why I decided to put the form in a function inside a static class I already used to 'render' all the HTML I will use a lot of times (such as Headers, logos, menus, etc)

```
//This is inside the HTMLRenderClass

renderTheEditForm() {

?>
<form>
    Name: *<br/>
    <input type="text" name="personalname" value="<?php if(isset($name)) echo $name; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    Last Name: *<br/>
    <input type="text" name="personallastname" value="<?php if(isset($lastname)) echo $lastname; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    Phone Number 1:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="personalphone1" value="<?php if(isset($phone1)) echo $phone1; ?>"/><br/><br/>


<!-- AND 53 FIELDS MORE -->


</form>    
<?PHP
}
```

All the variables that you see inside the VALUE attribute are the same as the ones that are being created dinamically in the FOREACH. When I paste the form HTML code below the Foreach, I can see the data being loaded, but when I use the Function from the HTMLRenderClass I get nothing... I haven't been able to find the reason.

I hope I explained well, thanks beforehand!

Comment: Would [`extract()`](php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) not work?

Comment: Why? Why create a level of indirection? Why not just use the original array values?

Comment: With 53 fields I'd just think of a different approach... How about storing all data in an array by `name`, `value` and `label` and generating the HTML with PHP in a loop?

Comment: your idea is wrong ,how are you assigning variables inside a function which are not defined ?

Comment: I agree with Arun. You must define those variables or pass them into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to define your variables inside the function or pass them into the function.

Comment: as clrockwell stated in the comments using extract is a one line replacement for the foreach loop (god forbid if one of the keys in the array is "owner")

Comment: It worked...

I declared the function that renders the FORM this way:

..static function renderTheForm($currentValues)

Comment: Try replacing `foreach($currentvalues as $key=>$value) { ${$key} = $value; }` with `extract($currentvalues);`

Comment: Using Extract() instead of a foreach loop works perfect... I just didn't know that Function.. Thank you!